# Can someone give me a counterexample to disprove this statement?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples

Claim :

> For any even number $n$ there is at least one prime number of the form :
>
> $$p=k\cdot2^{n}-1$$
>
> with following properties : $k=2^{a-n}+1 , n\leq a < 2n , $ and $a,n\in \mathbf{Z^{+}}$

Can someone give me a counterexample ?

I have checked statement for each $n$ up to $n=100$ , but I am also aware of [strong law of small numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Law_of_Small_Numbers) so this statement could be false.

**EDIT:**

One necessary condition is that there is at least one prime number on interval :

$[2^{n+1}-1,2^{2n-1}+2^{n}-1]$

One can easily show that this is true by using [Bertrand's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate).

Comment: Just to unfold the slightly convoluted definition, the condition is equivalent to $p=2^a+2^n-1$, or $p=2^{n+b}+2^n-1$ with $0\le b<n$.

Comment: If instead of primes we look for a random property distributed "like the primes" (according to the prime number theorem), the _expected number of hits_ for any $n$ tends towards $1$ for $n\to\infty$. The limiting distribution of number-of-hits would be somewhat Poisson-like, with uniform positive probability for each $n$ to have no hits. Of course, however, the primes are not randomly distributed ...

Comment: Where does this problem come from? What is the motivation?

Comment: @lhf,no specific source,my experimentation...motivation is to prove that there is infinitely many primes of the $p=k\cdot2^{n}-1$ form

Comment: Without the restriction on $k$, this is a special case of [Dirichlet's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)

Comment: @Henning,I put restrictions on $k$ because of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proth_numbers) form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the n=100 to 200 range, I think that 114, 134, 146 and 158 are all counterexamples.

Comment: you are right,I have checked them by Maple...thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica code:

mymax = 200;

mycount = Range[1, mymax];

Do[{n = 2*k;
  mya = Range[0, n - 1];
  mycount[[k]] = Count[PrimeQ[2^n + 2^(mya + n) - 1], True]}, {k, 1, 
  mymax}];

Count[mycount, 0]

The output is 9. This tell me that there are 9 counterexamples between n = 2 and n = 400. Peter listed four between 100 and 200, and there are 5 more between 200 and 400.

Comment: you are right,I have checked Peter's counterexamples by Maple..thanks